# Copy paste Text not working - inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am using Inkscape 0.91 on Windows 7. I am facing a strange problem in Inkscape. Whenever I am trying to paste content I have copied from the notepad, I am not able to as it says "nothing in the Clipboard". Please help.

[image]

Comment: Relevant forum threads: [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1181252), [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5bbc11e8-ca2d-41ac-b640-d66ce971f58f/copy-paste-clipboard-issues-not-working) and [here](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=13540). Some reports have to do with remote desktop running.

Answer (score 4):

I closed Inkscape and opened again. It worked after that.

Looks like a bug. Many have complained about it.

Comment: It's 2020 and the problem persists. Thanks for the workaround, though :-)